# Lightning Components: Will jQuery be unusable after Summer'17 and in future releases?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, jquery, locker-service

I read a lot about Locker Service becomes more and more powerful, restricting what we do (or hack) in Lightning Components.

Will the 3rd party library jQuery be unusable after Summer'17?

I'am aware that it will be jailed into the DOM of the component loading it - or it will have only access to the DOM elements where a $(...) is invoked. But within that limitation: will it work or not at all?

Comment: I think I recall Doug Chasman saying at the dev breakfast during Dreamforce that they're working on compatibility with jQuery and some of the other popular libraries out there.

Comment: See @TrevorBliss comments below my answer to a question [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/150358/2212) regarding support for jQuery libraries and locker service. I think that may provide you with additional insight and perhaps an answer to your question.

Comment: There are currently no known issues with LockerService and jQuery 2.2.4 that I'm aware of. Some may still be pending release, but none that have been reported that haven't been investigated and resolved in the main codeline. Obviously the whole jQuery API + DOM + all supported browsers is a large surface area so we may have missed a spot. If you think you've found a bug please provide repro steps and we'll investigate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things with Jquery now:-

It will work with your components if, carefully DOM selectors are used.

- Only basic one like changing css, attribute etc. Don't register
  Events.
- Second thing is, it will break any point of time because Jquery is
  stable but Lightning is not.

It is said that Locker Service allows you to manipulate DOM in scope or in other words we can access DOM elements inside the components elements and perform javascript operations.
Actually, the full truth is, we can access DOM element with in the scope and perform a **limited set of operation allowed** by Locker service. A large set of functions Locker service disable for DOM elements within scope. So, there are ample chances of Jquery break.

Comment: Thanks @Ashwani - You said that Lightning Components are not stable. Are Lightning Componets and Lightning Experience still BETA or GA? I was not able to dig this out of the documentation. At least what I can say both feel pretty BETA, but that's a gut feeling only...

Comment: Lightning is more and more stable, but LockerService is not perfect yet (still lots of bugs/limitations to solve) ... but it will be one day probably :)

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy Lighting framework is better than before but once we go in advanced level we start getting GACK errors.  Locker Service is a real issue. I agree.

Comment: @Ashwani are you seeing any specific issues with LockerService and jQuery 2.2.4?

Comment: @TrevorBliss it depends on how you define "issue". I think it works "as designed". However the consequences of the design are real-live issues. See comments from Praveen at my answer.

Comment: @UweHeim I completely agree with you. Here's one such issue. [Unable to add custom scroll due to “component/namespace encapsulation” when Locker Service is active](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151463/unable-to-add-custom-scroll-due-to-component-namespace-encapsulation-when-lock) Also, TrevorBliss has told that there's no update on this yet [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127300/window-access-on-secure-dom-lockerservice/127566?noredirect=1#comment223160_127566)

Answer (score 1):

Basically jquery seems to work, but what puzzled me first, is that it was not able to select DOM-Elemets inside my own components. It turned out not to work selecting sub-components if they belong to their own namespace like e.g. force:inputField.

Currently due to a bug force:inputField bound to a multiselect picklist-field renders in HTML as a disabled select.

So I have a `<select disabled="" ... >` somewhere in my components sub-DOM - and I know that for sure.

Now I put `console.log( $("select:disabled") );` in afterRerender().

Having the critical update disabled, I get the expected result, like: `Object[select#60:575;a.select]`

After enabling the critical update, I get only `Object[ ]` - so jQuery could not see into the DOM created by force:inputField. This is caused by Locker Service and as far as I understood a feature and by design.

Comment: Try scoping the selector to make sure you are searching only the DOM you are supposed to see.

Comment: I tried using jquery v2.2.4 in my component to alter DOM of disabled select in rerender and it works fine.

Comment: @Uwe Heim can you please share your markup for this case (or a simplified repro)? One important thing to remember is that the DOM elements are keyed to  the namespace of the component they're created by. So if your app is in the `c` namespace and your component uses a `<ui:inputSelect>`, even though the `<select>` element the `ui:inputSelect` creates could be considered inside your components DOM tree, the `<select>` is keyed to the `ui` namespace and thus your app is blocked from directly handling that element. You'd need to go through the `<ui:inputSelect>` public API.

Comment: @TrevorBliss : My markup in this example consists of a sole `<force:inputField>` bound to a multiselect picklist field. This renders in HTML as a disabled `<select>` (which is a Know-Issue, because it shouldn't be readonly). I've waited for a fix for over a year and now I want to match that `<select>` and fix the flaw with a one-liner in 5 minutes. But consider this only as an example. So maybe the whole point is, that LockerService prevents me from reaching into the markup produced by my force:inputField subcomponent? If so, I'll have to ask either another question or rephrase this one.

Comment: @UweHeim Since `<force:inputField />` belongs to `force` namespace you cannnot access the DOM due to Locker Service. With locker in place, you can only access the DOM that belong to your own namespace (default is `c`).

Comment: @Praveen Thanks, that clarified everything. So fixing bugs of others who should but don't fix them now strictly belongs to those others (the authors) - no matter what. And even for small glitches of others, we need to prepare for full waiting times and fall in love with IdeaExchange and Gogot. But I understand now how strictly this separation concept is designed.

Comment: @Praveen Can you please see if you've got to suggest a workaround for [Unable to add custom scroll due to “component/namespace encapsulation” when Locker Service is active](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151463/unable-to-add-custom-scroll-due-to-component-namespace-encapsulation-when-lock) ?